# Software for adjusting the velocity curve in Linux

Tags: midi-controller-keyboard

I use my yamaha clp330 digital piano as a midi controller. The problem is that the volume of the sound is too low when I play on the piano. But using software controllers the sound is normal. So it seems that the velocity value on my digital piano is set too low. I have Also set the touch on the piano to soft. I use Ubuntu Studio on my computer. Is there any software for linux for adjusting the velocity curve in realtime?

Answer (score 1):

the velocity values coming out your clp330 should be in the range 1-127 (0 is used for noteoff).  Record your clp330s velocities and see how they range.

almost every keyboard lets you pick "velocity curves".  How soft..hard maps to 1..127.  Some curves generate hi velocities even with softer keyhits.

So get your your manual, or download it from the yamaha website, and read up.  There's probably a setting for "velocity curve".

It could also be that the other tracks you have all are just using really hi velocities since nobody actually played those tracks live.  Tracks generated by software often ONLY use velocity=100.  You may need to edit THOSE tracks so they're softer and don't overwhelm you playing live.